# requestHeaders in http-conduit-1.9.4

Tags: haskell, http-request

I'm trying to create http request with custom header (with http-conduit-1.9.4 usage):

```hs
req <- parse "https://some_url"
let request = req { requestHeaders = [customHeader] }
```

And I don't understant what should be customHeader?
I have tried

```hs
import Network.HTTP.Headers
let custom_header = mkHeader (HdrCustom "Some-Header") "Some-Value"
```

but an error occured

```
Couldn't match expected type `Network.HTTP.Types.Header.Header'
                with actual type `Header'
    In the expression: custom_header
    In the `requestHeaders' field of a record
    In the expression: req {requestHeaders = [custom_header]}
```

also I have tried just

```hs
let custom_header = ("Some-Header", "Some-Value")
```

and error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Network.HTTP.Types.Header.HeaderName'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    In the expression: "User-Agent"
    In the expression: ("User-Agent", "erthalion")
    In the `requestHeaders' field of a record
```

So, anybody knows what should be customHeader?

Comment: The error tells that you need Header from `Network.HTTP.Types.Header` module and not from `Network.HTTP.Headers`

Comment: I know - I can't understand how create Network.HTTP.Types.Header object, and why it's different from Network.HTTP.Headers.Header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http-conduit does not use the HTTP package at all, they are two different approaches entirely. If you look in the [http-types](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-types/0.8.0/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Types-Header.html) documentation, you'll see that a `Header` is just a tuple of header name and value.

The only reason your `custom_header` didn't work is because you need to turn on the `OverloadedStrings` language extension.